# No option to import Table Valued Function in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

It's all getting a little messier for me, I just have picked up a project that uses EF (6.1.3) and uses System.Data.Entity (4.0.0.0)

First question would be: is this ok? To have `EntityFramework.dll` with version 6.1.3 and `System.Data.Entity` at 4.0.0.0?

Second: in this environment (db first), how do I import a table valued function to call?

Please let me know if you need any information around this.

I have searched over web, most of it says later versions of ef support TVF, but I guess using 6.1.3 is latest. So what am I missing here ?

Comment: Take a look at [Store Functions for Entity Framework Code First](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com). I didn't use it to push a TVF onto  the sql server, but I used it to make a TVF available through EF and it just worked.

Comment: thanks oliver, I have seen this approach but I am confused as to why some claim to be able to use tvf in same way as they can do sp ?